# Power BI - How to hide the token from dataset?

Tags: security, powerbi, token, powerquery

My dataset query in advanced editor window looks like the following:

```
let

iterations = 20,
  url= "url",
   FnGetOnePage = 
   (url) as record =>
let
 
 Response = Json.Document(Web.Contents(
     "https://client.product.com",
    [
         RelativePath = url, 
         Headers = [Authorization="bearer mytoken"]
       ]
   )),
```

I want to hide mytoken from this dataset, how can I do it?

Comment: you want a token that no one can find but you?

Comment: @horseyride correct ! like if someone download the dataset that person should not see the token or it should be encrypted

Comment: Can you use a dataflow (ie PQ online) to do your ETL and then have any reporting driven off the tables from the dataflow? That way your users have no visibility of the PQ script, they just set an end result table (or tables)